# SQL - Return Specific Part from XML log

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

My logging provider is outputting the following xml to sql in the following format:

```
-ID (int)
-Info (xml)
```

Xml format is:

```
<Info xmlns="http://loggingprovider">
  <Output>
    <columnNames>
      <name>sale_nbr</name>
    </columnNames>
    <rowValues>
      <value value="51500" />
    </rowValues>
  </Output>
</Info>
```

I am trying to return the list of sale_nbr (51500) from each info log but am having trouble with the particular xml type getting anything to return.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. XML support is **highly** vendor-specific

Answer (score 1):

You did not state your RDBMS, just as a hint (and to be the first ;-)   ) this is a solution for SQL Server:

First I declare a table with your two columns and fill it with your "Info". As you are declaring a default namespace (xmlns) it is necessary to use `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,Info XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,
'<Info xmlns="http://loggingprovider">
  <Output>
    <columnNames>
      <name>sale_nbr</name>
    </columnNames>
    <rowValues>
      <value value="51500" />
    </rowValues>
  </Output>
</Info>');

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://loggingprovider')
SELECT ID
      ,Info.value('(/Info/Output/rowValues/value/@value)[1]','int') AS sale_nbr
FROM @tbl AS tbl;

/* Result
ID  sale_nbr
1   51500
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it in DB2 (using @Shnugo example data)

```
select  base.*, info.*
from TABLENAME base,
  XMLTABLE('$info/*:Info/*:Output' passing Info as "info"
    COLUMNS

    val INTEGER PATH '*:rowValues/*:value/@value',
    name VARCHAR(200)  PATH '*:columnNames/*:name'
) as info
```

Answer (score 1):

The WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://loggingprovider') was the missing link. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi, I'm glad, that my answer could help you! Please allow me some hints: This is not an answer, rather a comment to my answer. Furthermore it would be very kind of you to mark the most helpful answer as accepted. This will show to the other users, that this question is solved. And: All professional giving answers here are hungry for reputation points. That's our "payment". :-)